# How to share boilerplate Kotlin configuration across multiple Gradle projects?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin

The [typical Kotlin configuration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) in a Gradle project is very boilerplate, and I'm looking for a way of abstracting it out into an external build script so that it can be reused.

I have a working solution (below), but it feels like a bit of a hack as the kotlin-gradle-plugin doesn't work out of the box this way.

It's messy to apply any non-standard plugin from an external script as you [can't apply the plugin by id](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-apply-a-plugin-to-a-project-from-a-shared-applied-gradle-file/7508), i.e.

`apply plugin: 'kotlin'` will result in `Plugin with id 'kotlin' not found.`

The simple (well, usually) workaround is to apply by the fully qualified classname of the plugin, i.e.

`apply plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper`

which in this case throws a nice little exception indicating that the plugin probably wasn't meant to be called this way:

```
Failed to determine source cofiguration of kotlin plugin. 
Can not download core. Please verify that this or any parent project
contains 'kotlin-gradle-plugin' in buildscript's classpath configuration.
```

So I managed to hack together a plugin (just a modified version of the [real plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.0.3/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinPluginWrapper.kt)) which forces it to find the plugin from the current buildscript.

**kotlin.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.0.3"
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: CustomKotlinPlugin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.CleanUpBuildListener
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPlugin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinTasksProvider

/**
 * Wrapper around the Kotlin plugin wrapper (this code is largely a refactoring of KotlinBasePluginWrapper).
 * This is required because the default behaviour expects the kotlin plugin to be applied from the project,
 * not from an external buildscript.
 */
class CustomKotlinPlugin extends KotlinBasePluginWrapper {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        // use String literal as KOTLIN_COMPILER_ENVIRONMENT_KEEPALIVE_PROPERTY constant isn't available
        System.setProperty("kotlin.environment.keepalive", "true")

        // just use the kotlin version defined in this script
        project.extensions.extraProperties?.set("kotlin.gradle.plugin.version", project.property('kotlin_version'))

        // get the plugin using the current buildscript
        def plugin = getPlugin(this.class.classLoader, project.buildscript)
        plugin.apply(project)

        def cleanUpBuildListener = new CleanUpBuildListener(this.class.classLoader, project)
        cleanUpBuildListener.buildStarted()
        project.gradle.addBuildListener(cleanUpBuildListener)
    }

    @Override
    Plugin<Project> getPlugin(ClassLoader pluginClassLoader, ScriptHandler scriptHandler){
        return new KotlinPlugin(scriptHandler, new KotlinTasksProvider(pluginClassLoader));
    }
}
```

This can then be applied in any project (i.e. `apply from: "kotlin.gradle"`) and you're up and running for Kotlin development.

It works, and I haven't had any issues yet, but I'm wondering if there is a better way? I'm not really keen on merging in changes to the plugin every time there's a new version of Kotlin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [nebula-kotlin-plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-kotlin-plugin). It seems very close to what you're trying to achieve there.

Comment: Well that's hilarious - I'm already using a handful of Netflix's nebula plugins (project, release, etc)....the kotlin plugin didn't exist last time I looked. I will give this a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is a [known gradle bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1322) about the inability to apply plugins by id from init scripts. That's why you need to use fully qualified class name as a workaround.

E.g. I have the following in the init script and it works:

```groovy
apply plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPlatformJvmPlugin
```

By the way, I created a gradle plugin for preparing custom gradle distributions with common setup defined in init script - [custom-gradle-dist](http://gradle-dist.oss.harmonysoft.tech/). It works perfectly for my projects, e.g. a *build.gradle* for a library project looks like this (this is a complete file, all *repository*, *apply plugin*, *dependencies* etc setup is defined in the init script):

```groovy
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
}
```