# How to configure every Kotlin project in Gradle multi-project build?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, build, build.gradle

I have a project that uses a Gradle multi-project build.
Some of the sub-projects are written in Java, other newer ones in Kotlin.

We have one top-level `build.gradle` file. This file contains following part:

```
allprojects {
    plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {
        // All the stuff that all Java sub-projects have in common
        ...
    }
    // All the stuff that all sub-projects have in common
    ...
}
```

We now would like to introduce common settings for our Kotlin sub-projects, but I could not find out which `withType` to use.

The `build.gradle` files of our Kotlin projects start with

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.0"
}
```

but neither `withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm)` nor `withType(KotlinProject)` works.

What type do I have to use there? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share boilerplate Kotlin configuration across multiple Gradle projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117820/how-to-share-boilerplate-kotlin-configuration-across-multiple-gradle-projects)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reference the Kotlin plugin by its `id` instead of its type, as follows:

```
allprojects {

    plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {
        // All the stuff that all Java sub-projects have in common
        // ...
    }
    plugins.withId("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") {
        // All the stuff that all Kotlin sub-projects have in common
        // ...
    }    
}
```

For Java plugin it's easer and you can use `plugins.withType`, as it's a "core" Gradle plugin, and the `JavaPlugin` class can be used as it's part of the Gradle [Default Imports](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#script-default-imports) ( `import org.gradle.api.plugins.*` )

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to start to use a custom plugin for your project. This is exactly what the AndroidX team did

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.plugins.all {
            when (it) {
                    ...
                is KotlinBasePluginWrapper -> {
                    project.tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java).configureEach { compile ->
                        compile.kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors = true
                        compile.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You'll need to setup all the boiler plate to get this setup, but the long term payoff is high.

Read more

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/androidx/build/AndroidXPlugin.kt#186

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQC9-Rj2yLI&feature=youtu.be&t=429

Answer (score 2):

The kotlin plugin being applied is actually not `KotlinPlugin` but `KotlinPluginWrapper`. Also it's necessary to use the canonical name to find the type.

```
plugins.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper) {
    // All the stuff that all Kotlin sub-projects have in common
    ...
}
```

To catch all wrapper implementations, `KotlinBasePluginWrapper` could be used as well.